# Protocol problem with PyMc3 on jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pymc3

I am working with the following code, but I get an error

```
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt

with pm.Model() as model:
   alpha = 1.0/count_data.mean()  # Recall count_data is the
                               # variable that holds our txt counts
   lambda_1 = pm.Exponential("lambda_1", alpha)
   lambda_2 = pm.Exponential("lambda_2", alpha)

   tau = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower=0, upper=n_count_data - 1)

with model:
   idx = np.arange(n_count_data) # Index
   lambda_ = pm.math.switch(tau > idx, lambda_1, lambda_2)

with model:
   observation = pm.Poisson("obs", lambda_, observed=count_data)

with model:
   step = pm.Metropolis()
   trace = pm.sample(10000, tune=5000,step=step)
```

But I get the error

ValueError: must use protocol 4 or greater to copy this object; since **getnewargs_ex** returned keyword arguments.

I have windows-10, python-3.5.6,
pymc3- 3.5, ipython-6.5.0. Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like this exception is being thrown by the `joblib` library, which uses `pickle` to send the model to different processes. The easiest fix is to use only a single core, by changing the last line to

```
trace = pm.sample(10000, tune=5000, step=step, cores=1, chains=4)
```

It will be hard to diagnose the problem with `joblib` without more details. Creating a [fresh `conda` environment](https://conda.io/docs/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround suggested by colcarroll did not work for me. The behavior you are seeing is related to [PR#3140](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/3140) of PyMC3, which you may want to track there. The solution and/or workaround may depend on how you are running theano (with or without GPU support).